# Window focus hops between windows in The Gimp 2.6 on Ubuntu 12.04 - how do I configure this?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gimp

f I run the gimp and have one image open for editing and use hot keys to perform operations (e.g. Alt-I, s, 600, Alt-S), after I am done the focus moved from the editing window to the toolbox window. This means that I can not continue keystroke commands (e.g. Alt-F, A ...) as I have in previous versions, but must first use the mouse to put the focus back in the same window I was using just a moment before.

This is a new issue using Gimp 2.6 Ubuntu 12.04 ; I was able to do this without mouse-clicking in whatever version of Gimp is present in Ubuntu 10.04.

Is there a setting in Ubuntu, the window manager, or Gimp that I can change to get the old focus-preserving behavior back?

Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be a known bug, reported in Aug 2012. I don't see solution or work around   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/1033219

Answer (score 0):

Had the same annoying problem. Just found this:

http://voices.yahoo.com/ubuntu-hiding-gimp-toolbox-3449370.html

> I went on the hunt for a "fix" for this annoyance, and here is how
>   this "feature" can be turned off and allow for the toolbox to be
>   hidden behind the image window. Open GIMP (Applications > Graphics >
>   GIMP Image Editor). With Gimp open, From the Edit menu, select
>   Preferences. Locate and select Windows Management from the left hand
>   navigation. In the Window Management section you'll find "Window
>   Manager Hints." Change both the hint for the toolbox and other docks
>   to "Normal Window" and click OK.
>
> You will be prompted to restart GIMP with the following message:
>
> "You will have to restart GIMP for the following changes to take
>   effect:
>
> toolbox-window-hint
>   dock-window-hint"
>
> Click OK. Close and reopen Gimp. The Toolbox will now be able to be
>   hidden behind the main window.